# iTunes connect will not let me add myself as a user

Tags: app-store-connect

I am working on an app in iTunes connect for a client, under their iTunes connect account. I want to add myself as a user so that I can get email notifications of updates in app status. When I try to add myself as a user I get the following message:

> The email address you entered already belongs to an iTunes Connect account. To continue, enter a different email address

I am using this email address on my own company's iTunes connect account, but not on my client's account. How can I add myself as a user?

Comment: I wonder if the Apple iTunes address comparison thingy would be fooled by an [address extension](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter) such as `foo@example.com` and `foo+customer_name@example.com`?

Comment: Read more https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html

Comment: Seems Apple got wise to this trick.  Tried it with <account>+<client>@me.com and got a message that I couldn't create an account with this address.

Comment: I used this less than a month ago. Possibly something changed since then though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about user account management in iTunes Connect, not programming. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276152/1402846

Answer (score 157, accepted):

@sarnold Turning your comment into an answer because it worked for me.

## Two Separate Websites

Apparently for historical and organizational reasons, Apple operates their developer and app store business in a bifurcated manner.

- [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/)

  The web site for all the technical resources, including documentation, WWDC videos and such.
- [itunesconnect.apple.com](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/)

  This **completely separate** web site handles the business end:

  - Contracts, banking, payments.
  - Uploading your finished app.
  - Defining your *In-App Purchase* products.

## Problem: Different Handling Of Accounts

The developer.apple.com site is slick in that a programmer can have a single Apple ID used to join multiple developer accounts. She may work for three different companies, and be assigned a role on each of those companies’ Developer accounts all on the same Apple ID. When she logs in to the Developer site, she is presented with a popup menu asking which of the three companies’ Developer accounts she wants to access during this work session. Nice.

The problem: in iTunesConnect, not so nice. In iTunesConnect, the "admin" person cannot assign existing Apple IDs as members with a role. Very strange. The admin is forced to create a new ID for each person being adding to the team. That means the person joining must have multiple email address. If an admin tries to add you to their iTunesConnect with an email address already used on some other company's iTunesAccount, an error message reports that email address / Apple ID is already in use. Obviously the programming team running the iTunesConnect site could use some help from the Developer site's team. ☹

## Workaround: Email Address Trick

The workaround cited by sarnold involves a feature of email addresses. The spec for email servers has a feature where you can [extend your email address](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter). You can add a suffix to the first part of your email name by appending a "+" PLUS SIGN. From what I could figure out, the email software first looks for the extended name. If no such name is found, it drops the extension and looks again. If found, the shorter version of the email address is actually used.

So if the programmer Susan wants to use her email address `susan@example.com` for a second or third iTunesAccount, she tells her client's admin person at Acme Corporation to use something like this as her email address: `susan+acme.com@example.com`. Apple will still create a needless extra Apple ID for Susan, but at least Susan does not have to bother with creating and accessing extra email accounts. The emails sent by Apple will arrive at her `susan@example.com` address.

Susan double-checked this would work before talking to the admin person. She sent herself an email to `susan+acme.com@example.com` to make sure it arrived at the `susan@example.com` account.

Effectively, the email servers are not fooled by the extended email address, but iTunesConnect is fooled into creating an new Apple ID using an old email account.

[image: Diagram showing a person with a single Apple ID used on multiple accounts at developer.apple.com while multiple Apple IDs must be created for iTunesConnect.apple.com]

Comment: Susan still has to be signed in with her susan+acme.com@example.com on her (iPhone) device in order to be able to install the beta-app with Apple's TestFlight app.

Comment: Apparently Apple got wise to this trick.  Just tried it with <myaccount>+<client>@me.com and got a message that I couldn't set up an account with that address.

Comment: @EPage_Ed, I was able to setup an iTunes Connect account using the +<client> trick.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen Testflight now specifically mentions that you dont need to be signed in with the same email ID on the device. 
From the invite email, 
"You can accept this invitation with the Apple ID that you are currently using. Your Apple ID and the email address to which the invite was sent don't have to match.
To accept this invitation, you must have TestFlight installed on your iOS device."

Comment: @EPage_Ed Did you send yourself a `<myaccount>+<client>@me.com` email to test your email system (outside of iTunesConnect), as suggested in the Answer? Not every email server is accommodating.

Comment: @BasilBourque We can now create an Apple ID with the plus sign (it was only possible in the past via iTunes Connect). My preferred method now is to always create a dedicated email for each client, on the developer.apple.com site as well as on iTunes Connect. When you don't use the same email, you need Application Loader to submit your app and can't use Xcode to do it.

Comment: Regarding @Robin's comment (first comment), the app will appear in Test Flight if you launch it from your email app on the phone via the invitation email link.

Comment: The plus sign does not work anymore. iTC says it is an invalid email address. Apple found the workaround and decided to make it more difficult for us.

Comment: Seems like @zirinisp is right, says invalid email address with the + addresses now.

Answer (score 19):

Basically, you can't invite other iOS devs to review your efforts seems to be the result of this policy.

Comment: An interesting summary!

Comment: That is hugely unfortunate, but it is even worse than that. If say, your company builds apps for other companies who have their own iTunes Connect accounts, you can't even add yourself to more than one. (Short of using up another email address for an additional Apple ID.)

Comment: Interesting but correct summary. Apple's way of driving their developers crazy.

Answer (score 4):

I had (and have) the exact same problem... what makes me kinda like FlavorScape's suggestion ;)

What I did is something similar to sarnold's comment: I used an alternative email address (**_@gmail.com instead of _**@googlemail.com) and this actually created a new AppleID with this email address.

It works fine, but it would be so much better to just connect my actual Developer account to my client's.

The way it's like at the moment, I can not even access the developer resources and (most importantly) the provisioning center with the new Apple ID, so my client has to do create new provisioning profiles and stuff, which is pretty frustrating and complicated.
Additionally, it is a pain to let him test the Apps on his own devices, because of the developer certificate is installed on my Mac, not his, and I am therefore the only one (or better, my Mac is the only computer) that can install new provisioning profiles on his devices.

Is there a better way to connect the accounts and solve these problems?

Cheers,
Nils

Comment: You can export the p12 file from your keychain and send it to your client then he will also be able to use his mac to handle developer account and provisioning profile. Please correct me if I understood you wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Apple now will allow the same email address to be invited to multiple itunes connect accounts and no longer allows new emails to be added with the +.  Just a word of warning to others who were doing this the original post is now out of date with Apples new policy it seems.

Comment: but i have 1 more doubt , can user be added as the sandbox tester for the in-app purchase ? because user is admin and it can perform any role in account . then how in-app purchase can be done ? how the code would identify user as sandbox user during in-app purchase ? do you have any idea ? or user have to create and provide another email id for sandbox tester ? i am confused . even i have refereed apple document regarding sandbox user .

Comment: Are you installing directly from your server or using test flight?  I know in the past if you installed directly you could make fake email addresses inside itunes connect as a test account and test in app purchase.  It's possible this isn't the case though if you are using test flight and I haven't used that for testing in app purchases.

Answer (score -1):

@knl: The problem in the original question is specifically with iTunes Connect. If you want to be able to manage the Provisioning center -- to make profiles etc -- ask your client to add you to that account. Here are the steps:

1. Go to "Member Center"
2. Select the "People" tab
3. Click on invitations
4. Select "Invite person"
5. in the next screen they can select your role including "Member" (limited access) and "Admin" (full access)

Comment: To clarify, this answer works for developer.apple.com. The question was for itunesconnect.apple.com.

Answer (score -3):

From apple documentation:

> You can only create test user accounts using an iTunes Connect
>   accounts with the Admin or Technical role assigned to it. Test users
>   do not have access to iTunes Connect, but will be able to test in-app
>   purchases in a development environment on a registered test device.

[Link here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases_Robert/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html)