# Adding User in Itunes Connect Team

Tags: iphone

I am a newbie developer of iphone from last few months. I am uploading apps behalf of my clients.
So one of my client add my email id in his itunes connect account. I completed the procedures and successfully login into itunesconnect.apple.com and uploaded the app.

But now i have other client, who also wants me to upload his app.
I am giving him my email to add me in his team in itunes connect not in developer. I got invitation in developer.apple.com.
But now problem is when he add me as a user it gives error like this
"The email address you entered already belongs to an iTunes Connect account. To continue, enter a different email address."

So if it means that i have to give different user ids to different clients?? How can i use single email id for different client's teams.
Any suggestions on it. Please mind that i am facing problem in itunesconnect not in developer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related [iTunes connect will not let me add myself as a user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968901/itunes-connect-will-not-let-me-add-myself-as-a-user)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same problem, what I do now is either:

A.) Tell the Client you need the login credentials to submit the App.

- If they are iffy about giving that information out, request that they change the password temporarily until you're done submitting.

  **OR**

B.) Create another email address for that client.

- This is easy to do if your site is using Google Apps for Business/Domain, as you can setup dozens of emails

Option **A** suffices for most of my clients, have only had to use **B** once or twice. This saves the trouble in handling multiple email accounts, password, iTunesConnect, etc..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i knew these 2 options. I am wondering if there is a way to add same email in different teams.

Comment: There's not, if it's telling you `To continue, enter a **different** email address`.. you can't link 1 email to multiple iTunesConnect accounts, but you **can** link 1 email to Multiple Developer Accounts.

Comment: @djk No, there isn't. Though using Google Apps you're able to create several aliases to a single email i.e. 1@ipwnstuff.com, 2@ipwnstuff.com, et cetera, and you can set the account so **anything** you use before youremail@yourdomain.com will be sent to you.

Comment: Okay, Thanks @skram and ipwnstuff for answers.

Comment: Yes but then, your creating a new apple id, right? And we don't want a trillion apple IDs

Comment: Try address extensions as in [iTunes connect will not let me add myself as a user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968901/itunes-connect-will-not-let-me-add-myself-as-a-user). Something like `yourname+client@example.com` should work for [most mail servers](http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/07/20/plus-sign-in-email-addresses/).

Comment: **'yourname+client@example.com'** this is working for me.. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Apple now will allow the same email address to be added to multiple accounts.