# Existing iTunes connect to join a team

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

Currently I have an apple developer account and iTunes connect account. My client invited me to their apple developer account [not iTunes connect] as an admin role . 
I got the distribution certificate and app is now ready to submit.

Now the time to create new iOS app with iTunes connect.
But :

- Do they need to invite us for their iTunes connect?
- I believe existing iTunes connect account can't be invited by a team. Is that correct?
- How can I upload app to their account?

Can you please help me to solve my confusions.

Thanks and Best Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [iTunes connect will not let me add myself as a user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968901/itunes-connect-will-not-let-me-add-myself-as-a-user)

Comment: Correct, developer.apple.com lets one Apple ID join multiple teams. But iTunesConnect does not. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19737906/642706) for explanation and tips.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Thanks for reply :)
 So, what can be the solution? Creating new mail ID ?

Comment: @BasilBourque: If we create new mail ID, then it must be enrolled to apple developer program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all feedbacks.

Here how I resolved above issue :

**The problem:** 
I had an apple developer account along with by default (created with same credentials) iTunes-connect account. After that I joined with client team as Admin role. Here they didn't included for the iTunes account, instead they created a new account and shared credentials of the same. Now, I got the certificate. Also, I created App and filled details in the new iTunes account.

On the other side,in XCODE while validating/Submitting app, I was facing

> error :*ERROR ITMS-4088: " No software found with apple_id: xxxxxxx "
>   at Software assets.*

I was 100% sure that the App created at iTunes account was not visible to XCODE and hence the issue.

**The Solution :**
I exported app as ".ipa" file to my desktop. Then through awesome "*[Application Loader](https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/)*" I logged in with new iTunes connect account and I completed all the steps. App is ready to go :-)

Comment: I think the ITMS-4088 error occurs becoz you didn't add your new Account into Account Settings of Xcode. Once you done that, Xcode will sync all data of your new account, include app list. Thus, that error will disappear. Please inform me if I'm getting wrong.

Comment: One more thing: did they create a brand new ItunesConnect account to associate with Dev account of new team? If yes, I think the better solution is that: create a iTunesConnect account but it's related to YOUR existing email account. This is done by create an itunesConnect with email format looks like: youremail+teamName@gmail.com. The system will ignore the "+" sign and any character after that, so you can access new IC acc with your old email.

Comment: I followed instructions [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170341/cannot-seem-to-add-internal-testers-with-existing-itunes-connect-accounts), and [here](http://mokagio.github.io/tech-journal/2015/04/01/itunes-connect-multiple-accounts.html) (see step 1 in post) and got success.