# Error Message: "The email address you entered already belongs to an existing Apple account". How to have an email re-available for Sandbox testers?

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, apple-id

I accidentally added the tester email in the bad section in the iTunes Connect. There is two options:

[image]

The one I choose by mistake is the User iTunes Connect, but I had to choose the Testers Sandbox.

[image]

What I want now is simply to add the tester in the good section, but I have an error message that says:"That email address is already associated to an existing Apple id."

[image]

How to get an email available to sandbox testers in iTunes Connect?

(I check that [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366538/adding-sandbox-tester-in-itunes-connect-with-an-existing-apple-account), but it seems not to have solutions)

Comment: Did you get the answer for that error?

Comment: @vijju yep, you can do nothing for that email, the only thing you can do is adding +01 to the email before the @. For example if the email is mail@example.com you have to put mail+01@example.com and it will work properly

Comment: When login to iphone which email is to given for that?

Comment: @vijju you have first to add it like in my ticket in the tester sandbox section, but if you already add the email in the wrong section « itune connect », you have to add +01 like in my previous message fist in sandbox section, and then you connect your apple account in the phone (i.e mail+01@example.com)

Comment: Appstore does not show the proper error either its password issue or email issue so while entering the password add a punctuation mark, capital letter and number  along with the solution purposed by @vijju.