# Test Flight: "The invite has already been used"

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes-app

I'm sending my client a build through Test Flight (via iTunes Connect) and he's receiving this error in Test Flight app when opening link coming from iTunes Connect

[image: Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be caused by a number of reasons.

1. Try to send another invitation to him
   The easiest way to solve this problem is to send another invitation to the person who tests it. Either register another internal user for testing or get another email via external users.
2. Do not open the link on your computer or iPhone
   Since TestFlight was taken over by Apple, builds aren't tied to devices anymore, what leads to apple distributing apps by unique links. Each and every link you get an be used only once. If  you open this link or install a build through it it becomes unusable.
3. Apple's Mistake
   There's a minor chance that Apple made a mistake and gave you a used link. This is my last point, as the odds are really small.

In any way, just resend a new link. You can do that by following point 1.

I hope that helps.

Julian

**Edit:**
As the asker himself added as comment, only adding a user won't make the trick. You have to enable Internal Testing for him under users and roles and also turn on internal testing for the app too. The problem was resolved, as the "client" was sharing his link and using it twice, even that doesn't work

Comment: Also, adding a new internal user in iTunes connect is NOT enough, one must turn on the  "Internal Tester" toggle  in their listing as well as check mark  their listing in the build and press the "Invite" button. Would be better if it was all done automatically.

Comment: It would definitely be. Sorry. I assumed that would be automatically  implied through my answer as you have previously done that anyways. But thanks. I'll edit it in now :-)

Comment: It turns out that my two clients were sharing the same email address and were both trying to install the build via the same link - as @Julian wrote the link may only be used once per device

Comment: Haha. great that my answer helped :-)

Comment: Also, Apple can be annoying as you cannot add a new internal tester email if Apple already knows about it somehow from another project - to overcome this annoyance see this creative solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968901/itunes-connect-will-not-let-me-add-myself-as-a-user

Comment: yeah. But you can also just add an email to internal testers, without making a new account. that works for me every time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding the same user again to the testflight account wont work.
If you accepted the invitation and the app showed in your Testflight app, that will remain there on all devices(associated with the same Apple Id).
If you need to download TestFlight to another device, it can be downloaded from the App Store. Your previously accepted invitations will show up when you download TestFlight on another device.