# Developer account tied to iTunes Connect - publish for another organization?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Edit:
On my organization,

- `a@b.com` is the legal/admin user in iTunes Connect and part of several development organizations, including company X.
- `a@b.com` cannot be added to the iTunes Connect account for company X because it is the primary account for my company.
- `c@d.com` has iTunes Connect admin rights for company X.
- `a@b.com` has admin rights on the developer account for company X.
- I create `a+t@b.com` as a new Apple ID.
- I invite `a+t@b.com` to iTunes Connect using `c@d.com`. This works fine.
- I invite `a+t@b.com` to the developer organization of company X using `a@b.com`.
- I cannot accept the invite because a+t@b.com is prompted to join a developer program. If I hit any buttons here, I get `Member Center agreement has already been accepted`.
- If I add `a+t@b.com` as an account in Xcode, it shows as under no teams, and therefore cannot publish.
- If I attempt to publish as `a@b.com`, I cannot, because I don't have iTunes Connect rights on company X.
- If I attempt to publish as `c@d.com`, I cannot, because I don't have iTunes Connect rights on company X.

I have an Apple ID I use to login to the developer center and iTunes connect. I've been added to another organization account as a developer, and I can make builds fine. When I try to publish the app, however, I get blocked because I don't have access to iTunes connect for the organization.

When I go to add myself to the new organization, I get this message:

```
"The email address you entered already belongs to an iTunes Connect account. To continue, enter a different email address."
```

However, any other email address I enter won't have my paid Apple Developer subscription, so I can only publish apps as `stefankendall@gmail.com`.

How can I add a developer to iTunes Connect and the member center as part of an organization that can publish apps? Is the only solution to buy another developer membership for this specific organization, and every other organization I would need to publish for?

The question flagged as duplicate is not applicable, since I'm the primary account holder of the first iTunes Connect account. I see no way to change the legal/admin user of an iTunes Connect organization.

[image]

[image]

[image]

...and then I'm not part of the team.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iTunes connect will not let me add myself as a user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968901/itunes-connect-will-not-let-me-add-myself-as-a-user)

Comment: You need to remove yourself from another iTunes Connect account before adding your Apple ID to another.

Comment: @JAL I am the account holder on the other iTunes Connect account, the admin/legal user. Is there any way to change the primary apple ID associated with an iTunes Connect organization account?

Comment: Get a new Apple ID. I usually let the other company give me an email and create a new Apple ID with that one. Also helps with communications separation.

Comment: @JustSid that other apple ID needs to be enrolled in a developer program to run apps, so that's $99, right?

Comment: @StefanKendall nope, any fresh Apple ID will work. If it needs access to developer resources outside of iTunes Connect, the company will most likely have a company developer account which they can invite you on as agent.

Comment: @JustSid I went through this entire flow, and I was unable to accept the team invite because the new Apple ID did not have a developer membership.

Comment: Even just for iTunes connect? I know that I have a few Apple IDs just for iTunes Connect and am pretty certain they are not members of a developer program. I'm currently on a plane about to depart, but I'll check after landing to verify that this is really the case.

Comment: @JustSid to publish an app, you need to be part of the developer team and authorized in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to Apple ID management and re-verify your email for the +extension@gmail.com email.

Answer (score 1):

### Original

Officially there is no solution for this as Apple does not offer a way to use multiple accounts. A hack for this is to use this format: **someone+organization@domain.com**. Apple will recognize this email as **someone@domain.com** where you will receive your confirmation email from Apple to be registered as a new user.

When you login use: **someone+organization@domain.com** alongside with your password.

References:
[iTunes connect will not let me add myself as a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968901/itunes-connect-will-not-let-me-add-myself-as-a-user)

### Update

When you face the error below, it is related to the confirmation of the **Apple ID Account**

> Member Center agreement has already been accepted

#### Solution

1. Head up to [https://appleid.apple.com/](https://appleid.apple.com), Sign In with the Credentials that you created on iTunes Connect and confirm the account
2. Apple will send you an email at **a+t@b.com**, click on the link and confirm it with **a+b@t.com** alongside your password
3. Find on your **a@b.com** email the invitation that you got from Apple to join the team
4. Logout from any account in **Apple Developer**
5. Click on the link from the email
6. Login with **a+t@b.com** under the link and confirm the Development Team invitation

Now you are on both **iTunes Connect** and **Development Team** and under **Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts** you should see that **a+t@b.com**'s account is part of your company's team.

*To force refresh remove the **a+t@b.com** account and re-add it again, and it should fetch the latest data.*

Comment: I tried this as well. I get an error when trying to join the development team "You have already accepted the member center agreement", and then I'm not added to the development team. I can add an account like this to iTunes Connect with no issue.

Comment: Now you are twisting things, Member Center is about provisioning profiles and creating the archived application, meanwhile iTunes Connect is about shipping that application. It seems you have misconfigured it, you need to be developer on Member Center with your **someone@domain.com** for the Company, refresh your account, and on General set the team to the Company. Then when you finish archiving, and submit it to the store, you need the account that corresponds to your team which is **someone+company@domain.com**. This work correctly, as I just did it.

Comment: When you hit "Submit to App Store" in Xcode, you need to select a development team. If a user isn't part of the development team, you can't publish to iTunes Connect.

So I need a user both in iTunes Connect *AND* and on a development team, and my goal is to do this without paying an extra $99. As I've stated, stefankendall+new@gmail.com has issues joining the other organization's development team, as I've described above.

Comment: @StefanKendall **someone+company@domain.com** doesn't need to be added to development team, you just need it on iTunes Connect. **someone@domain.com** must have Developer Rights on developer.apple.com for your company. You just need to add **someone+company@domain.com** to Xcode Accounts under Preferences, in order to be shown when you click on submit. So your steps are: Archive the app with **someone@domain.com** with team set your company, and then submit it via **someone+company@domain.com**

Comment: A+B@C.com does have permissions on iTunes Connect, and when I hit publish I *must* select a profile that has rights on BOTH, or I 1.) can't select the company on publish or 2.) get an error stating I don't have permission in iTunes Connect.

Comment: No when you click publish, you need to select **someone+company@domain.com**, which must be linked with your Team that you selected when you archived the application with. So please do repeat the steps to archive the app using  **someone@domain.com**, and then submit it with  **someone+company@domain.com**. If errors are present, then you need to be sure that  **someone@domain.com** has developer rights for the team (when you login on developer.apple it asks you under which team you want to login), and then check if  **someone+company@domain.com** has access on iTunes Connect. Let me know

Comment: From my question:

"I cannot accept the invite because a+t@b.com is prompted to join a developer program. If I hit any buttons here, I get Member Center agreement has already been accepted."

Comment: I'll take a full video tonight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87910/discussion-between-eridb-and-stefan-kendall).

Comment: @StefanKendall I edited the answer, please see the new update regarding to your changes on your question.

Comment: @StefanKendall Any luck yet?

Answer (score 0):

create a new Apple ID, either with an email you create for the organization, or an email they give you. Signup with that email, add that account to your xcode, and publish the app from that account.

There is no reason for you to go through the hassle of switching the default on your personal account for this organization.

Comment: So pay $99 for another developer program membership?

Comment: Yes, however if it is a company that wants you to release an app for them, they can pay $199 for a company account. Otherwise, a person's name will be used in the AppStore.

Comment: It's a company account. But I'm still having issues.

Answer (score -1):

You need a new AppleID which has access to iTunesConnect of that other organization. If you have access to an account with admin rights in iTunesConnect for that organization, log in under it and go to "Users and roles". Since it is an organization, there are several users there. And there is a plus button next to "Users":

[image: iTunesConnect Users and roles]

Click the plus. There you can enter the new user's name, surname and email (it will be used as an Apple ID). You can also use an existing AppleID, which is not yet registered in the iTunesConnect (iTunesConnect will show you a warning, but it's fine).

This will create an account capable of publishing apps for that organization.

Then in the Xcode settings ("Accounts" tab) you add your new account.
[image: Xcode settings].

Then when you submit the app, you'll be asked to choose an account to use for submission:

[image: App submission]

Unfortunately, I don't remember if you have to register your new AppleID in the DeveloperCenter as well as in the iTunesConnect. But even if you have to, it should be easy to do: you just add it as another ID in the organization (you need to have a right to invite new users to the organization for this, of course).

Comment: I've tried exactly this to get the error I'm having.

Comment: @StefanKendall, yes, sorry, didn't figure that out. You definitely don't have to pay 99$. Your problem ("you've already agreed to terms...") might be caused by the fact that you tried to accept an invite, while you were logged in as your first Apple ID in iTunesConnect. Try accepting an invite in incognito mode. Or in another browser. As far as I remember, it helped me.

Comment: A good assumption, but no. I was using different browsers and private tabs. This was my first assumption, but it was wrong.

Comment: @StefanKendall, well, sorry for wasting your time then. I remember that I encountered the same issue, but I thought that measures that I described were enough to resolve it. If I remember how I resolved it in the end, I will update my answer and let you know.