# iTunes Connect account jacked by other iTunes Connect Account

Tags: app-store-connect

Currently, I have access to two iTunes Connect accounts with different Email IDs. I wanted to test an App on one of account with TestFlight so I added the other iTunes Connect Email ID as my devices use that email id as their Apple ID. Now my original account is jacked and has no Administrative rights.
How do I get back administrative privileges back on the other account.

I referred to this Related Question: [iTunes connect will not let me add myself as a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968901/itunes-connect-will-not-let-me-add-myself-as-a-user). But now it's too late, I can't administrate my own account

This is my iTunes Connect Account User & Roles screen
[image: iTunes Connect Account User & Roles]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote to Apple Developer Support and opened a ticket. Apple guys resolved this problem for me. I got back my admin account privileges in my Team Account
[image: iTunes Connect]