# Multiple Individual App Developer Accounts

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having a weird issues with Xcode. I have an Individual Developer Account under my name. Now, I am working for a client and they have added me as a "App Manager" for their app. The client's account is also an "Individual Developer Account".

When I use Xcode and try to send the app to the App Store, Xcode always complain that the provisioning profile I am using is not contained in the Development Team settings. In Development Team settings I only see my own personal account and not the clients team name. My name email is used for my personal account and the member of the client's team name.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Xcode preferences -> Selecting User -> View Details at the bottom. Even if I click download it does not download anything. Keep in mind that the email I am using is not registered as a Apple Developer. [image]

Answer (score 0):

## developer.apple.com != iTunesConnect

You may be confusing the [*Apple Developer*](https://developer.apple.com) site with the completely separate [*iTunesConnect*](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) site. The first is for all the technical stuff, and the second is for the business stuff (submitting app, sales, etc.).

See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737906/642706) to a similar question to explain membership on each site.

## Create a new Apple ID to satisfy iTunesConnect

In *iTunesConnect*, the "admin" person cannot assign existing Apple IDs as members with a role. Very strange. The admin is forced to create a new ID for each person being adding to the team. That means the person joining must have multiple email address. See my other Answer for a workaround to reuse your same email account.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I added a new email address like myemail+clientname@gmail.com. I created the iTunes account for that new email. I opened Xcode and then added the new email as a new account under preferences. But now when I select the new team it says unable to download provisioning profile. I am using Xcode 8 Beta 6. PLEASE SEE UPDATED QUESTION.