# Multiple iTunes Connect accounts

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I want to create a new iTunesConnect account to distribute apps, but also be able to use the same devices to develop and distribute apps (Xcode, iPhones, etc).

I want to do this with the least headache possible and just have one email address and be able to toggle my two accounts both in developer.apple, itunesConnect, and Xcode.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42227324/7842955) that:

> Apple now will allow the same email address to be invited to multiple
>   itunes connect accounts

How should I go about doing this? I'm looking around developer.apple.com and I am not seeing anyway to add a new membership to the Apple Developer Program. Do I have to create a totally new account? Do I have to set up Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles again?

Thanks.

Note: this is on topic!
[Are questions about iTunes Connect on topic on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276148/are-questions-about-itunes-connect-on-topic-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: While an Apple ID can be a member of multiple developer teams, a given id can only be the primary id for one team, so you would need to create a new membership with a new id and then you could invite your existing id to become a member of that team. Each team has its own certificates, provisioning profiles, legal agreements etc

Comment: @Paulw11 I see. So only one Apple Id can make a team. A new membership is required for each team (with it's own billing etc.). But if say, some other developer had an account, he could invite me to his team to work with him on some app. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

An Apple ID can only be the **Agent** (on Apple Developer Center) and **Admin** + **Legal** (on iTunes Connect) for one team. So for each new team, you need to create a new Apple ID.

Please note that there are 2 different types of developer accounts:

- **"Individual":** Can only invite team members to iTunes Connect (Limits capabilities greatly)
- **"Organisation":** Can also invite team members to Apple Developer Center

Price is the same for both: $99/year