# "This email address is already linked to a provider. To continue, enter a different email address."

Tags: ios, error-handling, user-roles, apple-id

I tried adding new user in iTunes but it displays the error message as "This email address is already linked to a provider. To continue, enter a different email address." But this is happening for the particular ID. I have tried adding another ID and it's working fine. Can anyone help me with finding the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTunes connect will not let me add myself as a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968901/itunes-connect-will-not-let-me-add-myself-as-a-user)